# trigger in mysql between two database in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need a trigger between two database when a row insert to tbl1 in db1,this row insert into tbl2 in db2.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_users` AFTER INSERT ON `db1`.`tbl1`
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `db2`.`tbl2` (id,email,password)
VALUES
(???)
```

what is write in VALUES??

Comment: Change `???` by: `NEW.id, NEW.email, NEW.password`, understanding that the column names are the same in both tables of both databases.

Comment: @wchiquito this is work in local but the user root without password, but in the server user and password is set for both of database and this trigger not work!help me!

Comment: An error is generated?

Comment: not insert any data in db2

Comment: See the example in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example:

```sql
mysql> CREATE DATABASE `db1`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE `db2`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `db1`;
Database changed

mysql> CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (
    ->     `id` INT UNSIGNED,
    ->     `email` VARCHAR(255),
    ->     `password` VARCHAR(255)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `update_users` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl1`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     INSERT INTO `db2`.`tbl2` (`id`, `email`, `password`)
    ->     VALUES
    ->     (NEW.`id`, NEW.`email`, NEW.`password`);
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> USE `db2`;
Database changed

mysql> CREATE TABLE `tbl2` (
    ->     `id` INT UNSIGNED,
    ->     `email` VARCHAR(255),
    ->     `password` VARCHAR(255)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `db1`;
Database changed

mysql> INSERT INTO `tbl1` VALUES (1, 'email@email.net', 'secret');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `email`, `password` FROM `tbl1`;
+------+-----------------+----------+
| id   | email           | password |
+------+-----------------+----------+
|    1 | email@email.net | secret   |
+------+-----------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `email`, `password` FROM `db2`.`tbl2`;
+------+-----------------+----------+
| id   | email           | password |
+------+-----------------+----------+
|    1 | email@email.net | secret   |
+------+-----------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```